# Deleting an item refered to by other items causes the items to be "mass edited" (can't trust the edited by on versions)

Tags: content-editor, link-database

This is nothing new. When an item/page is referred to by components on other pages, let's say that the data source of the components refers to the item. Then, when the item is deleted, all referencing item versions with the reference become "modified" by the user.

This is probably the case in the underlying code, but it doesn't make any sense for the user who deleted the item. They become the editor of many items they haven't touched, which causes some annoyance.

Has anyone else encountered this "error" from a user perspective? Any suggestions for a fix? (The item in the image had a teaser component with a data source referring to a page that was deleted)

[image]

Comment: Why does it cause annoyance? Its a true representation of what happened. Just because the content author doesn't understand that doesn't make it wrong. This isn't an error. What are you using the "edited by" field for?

Comment: "Edited by" was wrong, i meant the "Modified by" as seen in the image.

You could argue that it's "wrong" because the editor/user hasn't actually opened the pages and edited them, it's just a programatically triggered "mass edit" that happended with her user (which isn't ideal I would argue). 

It means that the "modified by" feature is practically useless for detemining if a user has actuallt modified a page (the page content) or not. Modify = actually consciously made changes to text / components.